# Selenium only runs second of two functions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a Python noob, so this may be some stupid thing I don't understand.

Let's say I have two functions that I'm calling in sequence:

```
def one():
    print "ONE"
def two():
    print "TWO"
one()
two()
```

When I run it I get

```
ONE
TWO
```

Now, I have two functions built with Selenium webdriver, and let's say each one finds and prints the text of an element:

```
def find_one():
    print driver.find_element_by_class_name('onething').text
def find_two():
    print driver.find_element_by_class_name('anotherthing').text
```

Let's assume that the output of `find_one()` is 'one thing' and the output of `find_two()` is 'another thing'. If I run:

```
find_one()
find_two()
```

you would expect it to print to the console:

```
one thing
another thing
```

but it doesn't. It only prints `another thing`!

If I run `find_one()` it works correctly. If I run `find_two()` it works correctly. But when I run them sequentially, it only prints `find_two()`.

What is especially baffling to me is that if I call the functions sequentially and drive it with Firefox, I can see it navigating to the element in `find_one()` and then navigating to the element in `find_two()`, yet only `find_two()` prints.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: **Try running the find_one() method only**, and see if it returns **"one thing"** or not.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue that resolved itself with a reboot. Perhaps a Python problem.

Comment: Can you please mark the question as answered?